# addAttribute fails in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3)

Tags: xcode, swift

This was working before upgrading to Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3.

```
var mutString : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "K2")
mutString.addAttribute(kCTSuperscriptAttributeName, value:-1, range:NSMakeRange(1, 1))
var result : String = mutString.string
```

The result should contain the string K2 (with "2" as a subscript).

But now I get this error:

> Cannot invoke `addAttribute` with an argument list of type `'(CFString!, value:Int, range:NSRange)'`

Please point me to the right solution/documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Just add "as! String" after the kCTSuperscriptAttributeName

Answer (score 0):

`addAttribute` accepts an argument list of type `(String, value: AnyObject, range: NSRange)`. The latter two seem to be fine, but you can't use a `CFString!` with this method.

You have to use the native Swift `String` type in Swift 1.2 (which marks a further departure from its Objective-C heritage). Changing `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName`'s type to `String` should solve the issue.